# Make first set of variables / variants force change the second set to the first selection in that list

Tags: jquery, radio-button, product-variations

I'm doing this in a Shopify store but it could really relate to anything involving multiple variations or variants.

My product has two series of variants. One for style and another for size. Using Radio Button input fields. Idea is I'd like it each time you select any option for the first set of variants (style), the second set automatically reverts to the first option no matter what.

I thought this code might work, but it doesn't.

```
$('#swatch-clearfix-0 input').change(function(){
  $('#swatch-clearfix-1 input').prop('selectedIndex',0);
});
```

Here's my example code I've condensed down somewhat to get rid of unnecessary code you don't need to see here:

```
<div id="swatch-clearfix-0" class="swatch clearfix" data-option-index="0" style="flex-wrap: wrap;">
  <label class="swatch-label">Style</label>
    <div data-value="Style 1" class="swatch-element style-1 available">
      <input id="swatch-0-style-1" class="swatch-0-style-1" type="radio" name="option-0" value="Style 1" checked />
        <label for="swatch-0-style-1">
          <span class="swatch-element__inner">
            Style 1
          </span>
        </label>
     </div>
     <div data-value="Style 2" class="swatch-element style-2 available">
       <input id="swatch-0-style-2" class="swatch-0-style-2" type="radio" name="option-0" value="Style 2" />
         <label for="swatch-0-style-2">
          <span class="swatch-element__inner">
           Style 2
          </span>
        </label>
      </div>
    <div data-value="Style 3" class="swatch-element style-3 available">
  <input id="swatch-0-style-3" class="swatch-0-style-3" type="radio" name="option-0" value="Style 3" />
    <label for="swatch-0-style-3">
      <span class="swatch-element__inner">
        Style 3
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="swatch-clearfix-1" class="swatch clearfix" data-option-index="1" style="flex-wrap: wrap;">
  <label class="swatch-label">Size </label>
    <div data-value="Size 1">
      <input id="swatch-1-1-size-1" class="swatch-1-1-size-1" type="radio" name="option-1" value="Size 1" checked />
        <label for="swatch-1-1-size-1">
          <span class="swatch-element__inner">
            Size 1
          </span>
        </label> 
      </div>
    <div data-value="Size 2">
      <input id="swatch-1-size-2" class="swatch-1-size-2" type="radio" name="option-1" value="Size 2" />
        <label for="swatch-1-size-2">
          <span class="swatch-element__inner">
            Size 2
          </span>
        </label>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: So if we change to **Style 2** the Size option go back to the default: **Small** *(or whatever)*?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do. No matter if you select Style, 1, 2 or 3 the Size always goes back to Size 1 or Small or whatever is first.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do:

1. Give all Style inputs a class `styleRadio`
2. Give all Size inputs a class `sizeRadio`

```js
$('.styleRadio').change(function(){
    $('.sizeRadio:not(:first)').prop('checked', false);
    $('.sizeRadio:first').prop('checked', true)
});

$('.sizeRadio').change(function(){
    $('.styleRadio:not(:first)').prop('checked', false);
    $('.styleRadio:first').prop('checked', true)
});
```

---

You could also give the **first/default** one a class `default` and do this. That way you aren't stuck at having the first one being the default.

```js
$('.styleRadio').change(function(){
    $('.sizeRadio:not(.default)').prop('checked', false);
    $('.sizeRadio.default').prop('checked', true)
});

// duplicate for size but *flip*.
```